# wrong table row prints from List

Tags: c#, razor

I have a razor mergefield named: `BookingId`.

A BookingId can be named: `CCFM384-3049`, `RJDd3248-34` or `EVO-23804f-fgg3`

If BookingId contains the word EVO I have to print the first table row, if the BookingId does not contain EVO I have to print the second table row.

I am testing with the BookingId: EVO-23804f-fgg3. But I still get the second tablerow printet. What can be wrong in my code here?

```
@if ((new List<string> { "EVO" }).Contains(Model.Order.EvoBookingId))
{
      <!-- First tablerow -->
      <tr>
        <th class="small-12 large-6 columns first">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th width="300">
                        <p class="text-left small-text-left"><strong>EVO:</strong></p>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </th>
        <th class="small-12 large-6 columns last">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th width="300">
                        <p class="text-left small-text-left">
                            This table contains EVO
                        </p>
                    </th>
                    <th class="expander"></th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </th>
    </tr>
}
else
{
<!-- Second tablerow -->
    <tr>
        <th class="small-12 large-6 columns first">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th width="300">
                        <p class="text-left small-text-left"><strong>EVO:</strong></p>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </th>
        <th class="small-12 large-6 columns last">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th width="300">
                        <p class="text-left small-text-left">

                            <br /><br />
                            This table does not contains EVO
                        </p>
                    </th>
                    <th class="expander"></th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </th>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got `List.Contains(string)`, which means that it will return true if any of the list elements is "EVO" in this case. That's not what you want. You want your string to contain "EVO", so the correct way is:

**If you want to match EVO anywhere in the string**

`Model.Order.EvoBookingId.Contains("EVO")`

**If you want the check to not be case sensitive**

`Model.Order.EvoBookingId.Contains("EVO", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

**If you want to match only the start (as your example looks like this is the case)**

`Model.Order.EvoBookingId.StartsWith("EVO")`

or

`Model.Order.EvoBookingId.StartsWith("EVO", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: I just tested the code. It works very good when the BookingId contains the word "Evo". If it test with a word there does not contain "EVO", I still got the message: "This table contains EVO".